# How to link a SharePoint list with a Word form?

Tags: list, sharepoint, ms-word, linker

I want to store Word forms into a library and then use them to populate with data from a SharePoint list. Push data from the list to the forms, by selecting one of them.

Has anyone do it? is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a mail merge kind of operation. Mail merge does not work with datasources with a HTTP path. The workaround to this is to map the document library as a network drive. When performing mail merge in Word, you would then select the drive as the source.

See Q 14 in this link for more info

[]: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826838

Answer (score 1):

Each list can only (I think) 1 form that is used as the template document. 
Make secondary lists for each Word form.

If you have a primary input list, then a workflow that recreates a list copy in the secondary list as per the required form.

This should force the secondary lists to populate data onto the form as per each type, then save the form back to your primary list.

A bit out of the way, but should be able to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word (2007/2010) quick parts to pull metadata from SharePoint, but it works only if you use document library and not a list.